# abstract algebra - a proof concerning a torsion group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Consider a group $G$. Suppose every element of $G$ has finite order. I want to prove that a finitely generated abelian group of this kind is finite. This idea of every element of $G$ having finite order is called a torsion group. I thought I would mention that just in case what I said above did not make sense.

Attempt: Let $g_{1}, g_{2}, ... g_{n}$ be $G$'s generators. Since $G$ is abelian, any element $g$ in $G$ can be written as $g = g_{1}^{e_{1}} * ... * g_{n}^{e_{n}}$. Since the generators $g_{i}$ have finite order $m_{i}$ then there are only $m_{1} * ... * m_{n}$ expressions of the form $g = g_{1}^{e_{1}} * ... * g_{n}^{e_{n}}$ with $1 \leq e_{i} \leq m_{i}$. So the order of $G = m_{1} * ... * m_{n}$ is finite.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, save your last statement--which isn't actually necessary. Namely, there is no reason to believe that $|G|$ is the product of the orders of its generators (what if you just threw on an extra generator for fun?).

Comment: Do you mean that I do not really need my last sentence? And the $*$ does not have to mean a product. I just used it to represent the operation that would be used. Should I take it out?

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is correct but you need to be slightly careful in distinguishing between products of integers and group multiplication. If $g_i$ has order $m_i$, then $m_i$ is an integer. In other words, $m_1*m_2*...*m_n$ must refer to a product of integers. Thus, it is improper to write $G=m_1*...*m_n$. Instead, consider $|G| \leq m_1*...*m_n$. In fact, so as to avoid confusion, it might actually be better to use the $*$ only in one context. Either let it refer to group multiplication or use it to denote a product of integers.